# Vertically align button in ionic2 app

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

In the app, the buttons under Edit column don't show vertically aligned with the other columns. It is always aligned at bottom which makes the row look bad.

[image: Screen shot]

The code is given below:

```html
<ion-row>

<ion-col col-3> {{item.projectname}} </ion-col>
<ion-col col-4> {{item.loginid}} </ion-col>
<ion-col col-3> {{item.password}} </ion-col>
<ion-col col-2>
    <button ion-button menuToggle strong *ngIf="buttonclicked"                
     (click)="editdata(item)"><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
 </button>
</ion-col>  
</ion-row>
```

Please guide in this regard.

Comment: In fact i think they are vertically aligned. But since some columns have 2 lines, it uses the middle of that. This causes it to look off center when there is just one line of text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I align it with the top row ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to your component:

```
ion-col {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If i understand correctly this will solve your issue by vertical aligning the text. (since the button is already centered)

P.S You should make a class for this so it does not affect every ion-col in your component!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added your CSS to the corresponding .scss file. But it didn't work.

Comment: That is weird, i've tested it with your html and it was working in my application. 

See this: https://plnkr.co/edit/l0GtPwi7hGvyo9mAD8R0?p=catalogue

I implemented the fix in this plunkr. Try if it works there.